# Importing Lightning Web Component CSS in Aura Component

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

Is it possible to use Lightning web component Css in Aura component Bundle or Visual Force Page?

Comment: what do you mean lightning web component css ?

Comment: As per winter 20 release we can share CSS style Rules. For reference http://salesforcecodex.com/2019/08/salesforce-winter-20-release-feature-enhancements-for-development/

Comment: I think you can only share the CSS style rules between LWC components - this works because you import the css. AURA components are namespaced which will prevent the css from working.

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to import the LWC CSS into an Aura.

However I had the same need so what I ended up doing is move the LWC CSS into a static resource CSS file. After that I imported that CSS in the Aura component and LWC component that needed it. This works.

Here's [how](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/apps_css_external_platform.htm) to do it in Aura:

```
<ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.resourceName}" />
```

And for multiple CSS files:

```
styles="{!join(',', 
$Resource.myStyles + '/stylesheetOne.css', 
$Resource.myStyles + '/moreStyles.css')}"
```

And here's [how](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_third_party_library) to do it in LWC:

```
import { loadStyle, loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import resourceName from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/resourceName';
loadStyle(this, resourceName + '/stylesheet.css');
```